# Wordpress / PHP - want to stop link / lightbox

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

Basically, trying to modify a theme to suit. I've got a PHP function that I can't seem to modify appropriately to stop it from creating a hand cursor when hovering as well as stopping it from opening the image as a lightbox style gallery when clicked. I am trying to basically make it do absolutely nothing, but have the viewer scroll through the images.

```
<?php 

    $project1Images = explode( ',', $project1Images );
    $project1ImagesLinks = explode( ',', $project1ImagesLinks );

    for ($i=0; $i < count($project1Images); $i++) { 
        $thumb_id       = CoSy_getImageId($project1Images[$i]);
        $thumb_obj      = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full');
        $thumb_width    = $thumb_obj[1];
        $thumb_height   = $thumb_obj[2];
        echo '<a href="'. esc_url($project1ImagesLinks[$i]) .'" rel="gallery">';
        echo '<img class="lazy" data-original="'. esc_url($project1Images[$i]) .'" alt="" data-width="'. esc_attr($thumb_width) .'" data-height="'. esc_attr($thumb_height) .'" >';
        echo '</a>';
    }

    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!!

P.s. - I have a good understanding of reading code, but am not a coder by any means.

Thanks.

Comment: the PHP code is useless, since php has NOTHING to do with cursors. you need to show the resulting html, and whatever css applies to that html.

Answer (score 0):

To remove hand cursor when hovering and stopping it from opening the image as a lightbox you need to remove

```
echo '<a href="'. esc_url($project1ImagesLinks[$i]) .'" rel="gallery">';
```

and

```
echo '</a>';
```